# Sorting N dimensional data

Tags: data-structures, sorting

What would be a good choice for a key to sort a complex number $(a+ib)$ or any $n$-dimensional data for that matter. Is using the magnitude of that vector a good choice rather than using  any one of the dimensions, or is there any other metric which would suit this?

This was asked to me in an interview (it went like "how can one sort complex numbers?") Since then I have been thinking if I was right or wrong. So as far as this question is concerned feel free to assume any application or any data.

Comment: Depends entirely on the application. Without knowing what you want to do with that data it's going to be hard to give a good answer.

Comment: agreed. Actually this was asked to me in an interview(it went like"how can one sort complex no.s") and since then I have been thinking if I was right or wrong. So as far as this question is concerned feel free to assume any application or any data.

Comment: I'm guessing they wanted some total order, in which case perhaps the easiest answer is to sort lexicographically: first by real part, and break ties by imaginary part. If you choose to map your complex numbers to some real metric then sort according to that, you will never* be guaranteed a total order. (* you could map to the distance between the origin and the considered number on some space filling curve, but then there are a whole bunch of issues regarding precision you probably wouldn't want to get into during such an interview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following would be natural choices for sorting complex numbers:

- **Lexicographic ordering, real first:** Sort $a + bi$ first by $a$, then by $b$. So $a + bi < c + di$ if $a < c$ OR if $a = c$ and $b < d$.
- **Lexicographic ordering, complex first:** $a + bi < c + di$ if $b < d$ OR if $b = d$ and $a < c$.
- **By magnitude:** $a + bi < c + di$ if $|a + bi| < |c + di|$.
- **By argument:** $a + bi < c + di$ if $\text{arg } a + bi < \text{arg } c + di$, where $\text{arg}$ is the angle of the complex number.

Of these, the first two have the advantage that they agree on the ordering of real numbers, which could often be important. The first two also have the advantage that they are **total** orderings rather than orderings where some elements are indistinguishable (for example, in the magnitude ordering, elements of the same magnitude are indistinguishable). The last two can be fixed to be total if you add a tiebreaker ordering, e.g. if two numbers have the same magnitude, then order them by argument, or vice versa.